# Using .dll pre-compiled(deployable) web applications with a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I would like to create a web portal that provides a user basic functionality, user authorization, statistics, etc. But on a lower level provide applications of various functionality.

Through research and lots of Google I think the best way to do this is making a web page project for the web portal and for easy source control, low coupling, and maintainability require all underneath applications to be a deploy-able dependency of the web portal. Thus! they all auto compile and upload at time of publishing the website! This seems great! BUT I cannot for the life of me figure out how to call the underlying webpages from under the .dll (deploy-able assembly).

Is this even possible? It seems it would be from what I can gather since you can compile a whole website (aspx and all) to a .dll. So how does one go about calling the web pages/applications in the .dll?

For example I'd hope to do something like this:
www.webpage.com/Default.aspx (root and web portal)
www.webpage.com/bin/application.dll/Default.aspx (the pre-compiled web application without routing)

Thanks!

EDIT:
I want to clarify that the idea is that one development group can maintain the web portal and others can build separate independent applications that will function underneath the portal. Separate projects to be included at compile time is a must. Perhaps this functionality is not possible?
The purpose of the older style web site project is because this project had been started sometime ago and is a resource for the project. If the project type introduces limitations it would be feasible to change it to a newer project type (ASP web application) if and only if it achieves my hopes as described above.

I was thinking it is a bit hacking but I could add a controller to the .dll that just provides the utility to return a whole aspx or ascx web ui component on demand to be sent to the client. There must be a better way though?

Comment: "ASP.NET Websites" were introduced in VS2005 but aren't a matter of much conversation thesedays; it seems we're all using the original "ASP.NET Application" project model introduced in VS2002. However your question's text suggests that you lack an understanding of how ASP.NET works. I suggest you use ASP.NET MVC instead of WebForms anyway.

Comment: Web Forms is still a valid use for building a web page. Based on the pros and cons of the designs I went with web forms for the project. I do like MVC and had considered it. It would be worth spending time to switch my project to MVC IF it is the only way to reach the functionality described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following...

1 Solution with 2 Projects.
 - a website (not web application)
 - a class library

The class library (ultimately compiled into a DLL) will be a project reference in your website and it will handle the bulk of the code. The website will have UI and some basic logic and of course will dictate the structure of the site, but will rely on the class library for the heavy lifting.

The beauty of this setup is centralized code and easy expandability. One of my solutions has 3 websites and a web service that share the same code base.

Comment: This would work but change the intention of my design allowing separate applications to be built underneath the web site project (web portal) and simply be added to the portal be adding a reference to the web site project. Is it impossible to achieve a website's UI being delivered from a .dll? or can a .dll only have utility function? This is confusing to me because the MSDN documentation alludes to compiled a whole web application (.aspx, ascx, and all) into a .dll.

Comment: My experience with web applications is all the *logic* is compiled into a DLL, but the UI is still separate .aspx files.

You could build the UI in code, but it would be a major undertaking and depending on how interactive your site is, you will probably run into issues with postbacks (controls added via code have to be re-added on each postback - which can cause major headaches with form submissions).

You could *cheat* a bit and use URL Routing and a route controller (for lack of a better term) to move all URLs to a single processing location.  Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: I think right now the .Net Framework does not support what I am trying to do very well. While it may be doable, it may also become quite painful thus! I think TrueDevelopment has the best answer here.